# How to understand non-invertible symmetries from stacking TQFTs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, conformal-field-theory

I'm reading section 3.3.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18296. The idea is to stack a 1d TQFT with G symmetry on a quantum field theory T with symmetry G, then gauge the diagonal G symmetry, the 1d TQFT will in general become the non-invertible topological lines in the gauged theory T/G.

Why does the 1d TQFT become the topological line in the gauged theory T/G after gauging? I thought it's a diagonal gauging in the sense that 1d TQFT will not talk to the quantum field theory T. Following this thinking, symmetry Rep(G) appears when gauging G in T. Why it's these TQFTs after gauging corresponds to the generator of Rep(G)?

To be more precise, stacking a 1 d TQFT on a 2 d QFT. It should not affect the local dynamics. Why after the diagonal gauging, it becomes the generators of the dual symmetry?

Comment: Although the 1d TQFT does not talk to the QFT $T$, the symmetry $G$ acts on both of them. So when you gauge $G$, the partition function in the presence of $G$ background receive contributions from both the QFT and the 1d TQFT. Thus the 1d TQFT does have effect on the dynamics of the gauged theory. More precisely, they act on $G$ defect operators, as $Rep(G)$ should do.

Comment: @MengCheng Hi Meng, thanks for the answer! Say I have a 2d G-QFT stacked with a 1d G-TQFT, after gauging the diagonal symmetry, I would get 2d Rep(G) 0-form symmetry product with 1d Rep(G) -1-form symmetry, I don’t really know what the product here should be, but anyway, both of them are lines, I guess these two could be the same? Could you point a reference where I could see it explicitly?

Comment: @MengCheng  But if I have a 3d G-QFT stacked with a 2d G-TQFT, after gauging the diagonal symmetry, I would get a 3d Rep(G) 1-form symmetry product with a 2 d Rep(G) 0-form symmetry, clearly the second symmetry gotten from TQFT will not become the symmetry gotten from the QFT. How to understand this?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding is that we gauge 0-form symmetry in both 2d G-QFT and the 1d G-TQFT. Similar in 3d (or any $n$d). In the 3d G-QFT stacked with a 2d G-TQFT case, when the 2d TQFT is invertible (SPT), then we do get an invertible topological defect in the gauged 3d theory. One reference that does this gauging SPT defect pretty thoroughly is https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.11764.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks! My counting in my last comment has messed up. Both of them should be line operators. However, I don't know the argument to argue they are indeed the same line operators... Thanks for the reference, I'll take a look.

Comment: @MengCheng Also, suppose I want to stack my 3d G-QFT with a 2d TQFT with G 1-form symmetry, from the topological operator point of view, it seems like I also could define a diagonal gauging. Is this a well-defined procedure?

Comment: For the 0-form $G$ in 2d case, maybe the following helps: a 1d indecomposable $G$-TQFT is basically an irrep $\pi$ of $G$, and after gauging, the wrapping action of the line on a $G$ defect operator (labeled by a conjugacy class $[g]$) should be $\chi_\pi(g)$, where $\chi$ is the character of $\pi$.

Comment: Interesting question. I would think you can gauge the diagonal 1-form symmetry, not sure what the outcome would look like.